Google App Engine to python3 migration for a specific service
I am deploying the following in sync.yaml. This was part of my python 2 project.
service: sync
instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
runtime: python312
app_engine_apis: true

# taskqueue and cron tasks can access admin urls

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: sync.app
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301

env_variables:
  MEMCACHE_USE_CROSS_COMPATIBLE_PROTOCOL: "True"
  NDB_USE_CROSS_COMPATIBLE_PICKLE_PROTOCOL: "True"
  DEFERRED_USE_CROSS_COMPATIBLE_PICKLE_PROTOCOL: "True"
  CURRENT_VERSION_TIMESTAMP: "1677721600" 

The handlers are defined in a file called sync.py. Will this handler call my python script called sync.py despite the reference saying sync.app?
The reason I'm asking is because when I call the urls referenced for sync, as specified by having the prefix 'sync' in the host name, I'm getting errors that lead me to believe it is calling main.py as specified in apps.yaml.
This pattern was working in python 2.
The url in question is https://sync-dot-project1.appspot.com/, i expect this to be handled by the service.
However, I suspect it is being handled by the default service as specified in app.yaml/main.py because it is redirecting to a "trusted site" ? which is one of the first operations in main.py
https://project1.appspot.com/


According to documentation for app.yaml for python 3,


script:
Optional. Specifies that requests to the specific handler should target your app. The only accepted value for the script element is auto because all traffic is served using the entrypoint command...


This means that script: sync.app isn't telling Google to call sync.py (that command is being ignored).

To tell Google to call sync.py (given that this isn't your default service), sync.py should have it's own app object and then you should have the following in sync.yaml
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT sync:app 



The above line starts a web server in sync.py and will then call the handlers for the different routes in that file.



Thank you! That connected the path. I also had to add gunicorn to requirements.txt

@ffejrekaburb - Yes, if you have an entrypoint, you need to add the web server software - documentation. You should accept the answer so that others in same boat will find it 'cos this is a significant change in behavior from Python 2

yes it is! Thank you for your help assimilating the information.


The handlers are defined in a file called sync.py. Will this handler call my python script called sync.py despite the reference saying sync.app?

Yes, it will call the sync.py file. It is explained in detail in this document.
In newer App Engine runtimes, the behavior of script field has changed.

In the Python 2 runtime, you use the script field to route incoming requests to your app's script.
In the Python 3 runtime, you are required to use a web framework with in-app routing (such as Flask or Django) instead of using the script field.
To migrate your app.yaml file to the Python 3 runtime, do one of the following, depending on whether the file contains static handlers as well as script handlers:
If your app.yaml file contains static handlers, do one of the following to ensure that requests for dynamic content are routed to your app's script:

Remove all script fields. Then add an entrypoint field to start a web server that runs your app. Requests that don't match any of your static handers will be directed to the web server you specified in the entrypoint field. The web server and your app's web framework are responsible for routing the request to the correct script.

Replace the value of all script fields with auto. App Engine will automatically run your app in a web server (assuming your app meets a few requirements), and all requests that match a script handler will be directed to the web server. The web server and your app's web framework are responsible for routing the request to the correct script.

If your app.yaml file does not contain static handlers, remove all script fields. All requests to your app will be directed to your app's web server, and your app's framework will route the request to the correct script. You can optionally add an entrypoint field to customize the default startup behavior. If your app.yaml has both types of handlers, you can still remove all the script handlers that would be marked auto, leaving behind the static handlers as well as auto handlers requiring other directives, such as the admin-only handler in the example below.



Also have a look at this Link1 and Link2 for reference.

Thank you, this helps me see the path.
app = flask.Flask(name)
....
@app.route('/rx/', methods=['GET'])
def rx():
What could cause /rx/ not to be triggered
The sync.yaml file is above

@ffejrekaburb - If you kept sync as the service name, then you have to access your routes via a specific url format - see documentation for the format.

Thanks, I have a sync.py which is run implicitly from the sync.app? Howver, it still seems to me that the calls to the sync service via url are running my main.py file.  How does google app engine determine which .py file to run?

@ffejrekaburb - Provide an example of the url you're trying to use to access a route in your sync service. Don't add it in comments. Add it to the question. Also include the specific error you get when you try to invoke the url.
